# How to know if debug version of flash is installed?

Tags: flash, debugging, version

How to know if debug version of flash is installed?
Thank you.

Comment: Visit Version Of Flash Player http://www.versionofflashplayer.com/ this should show you if your Flash Player is the debug version or not, and also provide the version number!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Right click on a flash movie, you should have *debug* in the menu if it is the debug version.

Or you can go to [the flash test page](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html) on Adobe's site. You can find the capabilities of the player at the bottom.

Comment: flash test page is not showing Debug Version: Yes/No any longer. But your right-click advice was good, thank you

Comment: flash test page DOES show debug if you click the "Check Now" button: "Your Flash Version | 16.0.0.296 **(debug version)**"

Answer (score 9):

Programmatically,

```
flash.system.Capabilities.isDebugger
```

Answer (score 8):

Adobe's got a page that will show you if it's the Debug Player or not:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html#main_Find_Flash_Player_version_type_and_capabilities__Flash_developers_only_

[image]

Comment: it says I'm on 32bit win7, not 64bit, so I'm not sure how right the rest of the info is.

Comment: With their usual style, Adobe apparently changed the page.  I don't see the Debug Player line any longer.  How irritating is that?

Answer (score 2):

Above pages didn't work for me. This one did: http://flashbuilder.eu/flash-player-version.html